# IOS: identify a generic object

Tags: ios, objective-c, object

In my app I should analyze an object and I do this:

```
 if ([object_selected isKindOfClass:[Person class]]) {

    Persone *obj = (Persone*)object_selected;
    NSString *name = obj.nome;
    NSString *surname = obj.surname;

}
else if ([object_selected isKindOfClass:[Animal class]]) {

        Animal *obj = (Animal*)object_selected;
        NSString *name = obj.nome;
        NSString *breed = obj.breed;

    }
```

in this way I should verify if my object belong to a class to obtain its property, but is there a faster way to obtain the property "name" from my objects?
All objects have "name" property.

thanks

Comment: Simply use [obj name], youll get a warning but if ALL objects responds to this property it works, if an object doesn't respond to the property "name", app will crash when you try to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call `[object_selected name]`, though you might get compiler warnings that `name may not be a property` (or similar).

Comment: Is the property named `name` or `nome`? I just noticed the property you are calling inside the `if`/`else if` is `nome`, but the property you listed in your question is `name`.

Answer (score 3):

The code aforementioned have a common issue: whenever the name property is missing it dumps core. Here is my version that is a hell lot safer, and a one-liner:

```
id name = ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(name)]) ? [object name] : nil;
```

Hope the ternary operator did not confise you. The nil can be replaced with whatever is appropriate if a name is not present, like:

```
static NSDictionary *defaultNameForClasses = @{@"FooClass": @"Foo", /* ... */};
// ...
id name = ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(name)]) ? [object name] : defaultNameForClasses[NSStringFromClass([object class])];
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Objective-C protocols at apple developer docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

Long story short:
You can define all the properties you need in a protocol, make your classes (Person, Animal e.t.c) follow it and then use `[object_selected conformsToProtocol:MyProtocol]` to safely get the property like this:

```
if ([object_selected conformsToProtocol:MyNamingProtocol]) {
  id<MyNamingProtocol> namedObject = object_selected;
  NSString *name = [namedObject name];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a protocol in a separate .h file. The code would look similar to the following:

> @protocol NamedObjectProtocol
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
>
> @end

Then, make both object classes declare conformance to this protocol. Then, you can cut the if/else spaghetti and get the property like this, irrespective of whether `anObject` is an instance of a `Person` or `Animal` class.

```
id <NamedObjectProtocol> namedObject = anObject;
NSString *name = namedObject.name;
```

You should also consider making the `Animal` and `Person` classes inherit from a superclass, which has all commonalities, such as the name property. This would allow you to write code like:

```
Character *character = anObject;
NSString *name = character.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) to safely access the property. Just use:

```
NSString* name = [object_selected valueForKey:@"nome"]
```

The advantage of this is that application won't crash if `object_selected` doesn't have a property called `name`, in this case the value of `name` variable will be `nil`.

Another way to avoid crash is to check if object responds to selector, like this

```
if ([object_selected respondsToSelector:@selector(name)]) {
//...
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same. There is just one downside to this approach. As the programmer you can not determine whether the value of an existing property is nil (which may have a meaning or indicate an error) or does just not exist (which may just indicate, that the object is of a different class).